# javascript document.submit not working in all browsers

Tags: php, javascript, browser

I have a problem with my code somewhere, when the user selects the "event" in the first select menu, it updates the 2nd menu with options from the database. This second menu is not updating in some browsers such as IE and Chrome, however works fine in others like firefox.

I'm not quite sure what is the problem, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

The code I currently have is below-

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript">
function events()
{
   document.eventform.submit();
}
</script>

<?
require_once('dbconnect.php');

$sql="SELECT id, event FROM events ORDER BY id DESC";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$options1="";

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$id=$row["id"];
$event=$row["event"];
$options1.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$event\">".$event;'</OPTION>';

}
$eventis = $_GET['event'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE event='$_GET[event]' ORDER BY id DESC";  
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$options2="";

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$id=$row["id"];
$location1=$row["location1"];
$location2=$row["location2"];
$location3=$row["location3"];
$location4=$row["location4"];
  $options2.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$location1\">".$location1;'</OPTION>';
$options2.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$location2\">".$location2;'</OPTION>';
$options2.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$location3\">".$location3;'</OPTION>';
$options2.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$location4\">".$location4;'</OPTION>';

}
?>
</head>
<body>


<form action=""  name="eventform" class="style1" id="eventform" onchange="events()">
  <p align="center">


Step 1: 
  <select name="event" id="event">
  <OPTION VALUE=0>Select Event:
  <?=$options1?>
  </select> 
  &nbsp;</label>
  <?php echo $eventis ?></p>
  <div align="center"></div>
  <div align="center"></div>
 </form>

 <form action='sale.php' name= 'locationform' method='get'>

<div id="eventname"></div>
<p align="center">Step 2: Select the location:
  <select name="location"  id="location">
 <OPTION VALUE=0>Select Location:
  <?=$options2?>
 </select>
</p>
<p align="center">
<input name="event" type="hidden" id="event" value="<?php echo $eventis ?>">
<input name="operator" type="hidden" id="operator" value="<?php echo $operator ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it valid HTML?  If not, then you can't expect it to work (though invalid HTML is very highly tolerated).  Also, you might want to look into SQL injection.

Comment: Shouldn't the onchange be on the select rather than the form? ..But ideally you would not submit the form with the change of the select value, rather you would just alter the options to the second select (whether through ajax or using one of several pre-loaded sets of options for the second select).

Comment: Thanks ghbarratt that's exactly what the problem was!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for starters your not selecting your form

`document.eventform.submit();`

Does not select your form, you will need to use

`document.forms["eventform"].submit()`

or select the form using `getElementById`.

Second your html is a bit of a disaster :) but I don't think that's the issue. Just thought I would let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Add end tag in both cases
    `<OPTION VALUE=0>Select Event:</OPTION>`
    `<OPTION VALUE=0>Select Location:</OPTION>`

Comment: Also, wrapping the value attribute in quotes is a good practice ;)